Expected speedup comparing x_videotoolbox vs x_libx encoding
I just got a new M3 pro mac and it is indeed much quicker than my previous intel based machine. However, I was expecting more of a speedup in doing h264/hevc_toolbox encoding compared to libx encoding. I find no real difference in h264 vs hevc whilst about 2*fps compared to libx encoding (getting about 200fps in hevc/h264 vs libx).
infile:   Duration: 00:08:26.40, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 24019 kb/s
Stream #0:00x1: Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 23995 kb/s, 50 fps, 50 tbr, 5k tbn (default)
Command I´ve been running with different encoders:
ffmpeg -f concat -i concat:mylist.txt -an -c:v h264_videotoolbox -q:v 50 -filter:v "fps=30"  test5.mp4
Does this resonate with other people or am I missing something.
